# Selenium/Java-How to make 'dataProvider' a common function inbetween multiple source folders

Tags: java, selenium, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

I have created a project with seperate source folder for each module, say **mod1** & **mod2** and the **src** source folder as common for each source folder.
And I created **DataProvider_Repository.java** file for reading data from excel sheet. Which now I need to put **Data Provider** in each source folder for accessing it in each testcase(Eg:Registration.java or Del.java).

How can I make it common & put in **src** folder.
**DataProvider_Repository.java** contains same code for reading data from excel sheet.

**DataProvider_Repository.java**

```
package online;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class DataProvider_Repository {

     @DataProvider(name="dataProviderRepo")
      public static Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider(Method m) throws IOException{

            Object[][] object  = null; 

            String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\";
            String fileName = "sample.xlsx";
            String sheetName= "sampleSheet";

            File file = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet  s = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

            //Find number of rows in excel file
            int rowCount = s.getLastRowNum()-s.getFirstRowNum();
            object = new Object[rowCount][6];

            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                //Loop over all the rows
                Row row = s.getRow(i+1);
                int lst = row.getLastCellNum();

                //Create a loop to print cell values in a row
                for (int j = 0; j < lst; j++) {
                    //Print excel data in console
                    if(row.getCell(j) != null){
                        object[i][j] = row.getCell(j).toString();
                    }
                }
                object[i][lst-1] = Integer.toString(i);
            }
            return object;   
        }
}
```

**Registration.java**

```
package online;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Registration {

    @Test(dataProviderClass=DataProvider_Repository.class,dataProvider="dataProviderRepo")
    public void OnlineRegs(String testcaseName,String keyword,String objectName,String objectType,String value, String rowNum) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("=======OnlineReg===========");   

        //Operations here...    

    }

}
```

**The folder structure is**

[image]

Comment: depending on the framework you are using, you can import one module to another and reuse the class OR if you dataProvider is generic enough move this class to entire different module and use it as a library(import it)

Comment: ok..let me try to use as module. I am using testng-hybrid framework

Comment: can you not import the package for the DataProvider class directly in both the modules? (just asking)

Comment: ya..i have started selenium one month before & am trying to make all possible generic classes common. I think i can make the test cases(Registration.java or Del.java) also into a single by using suite or something, as both contain almost generic things.

Comment: @Adithya Please check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/40966263/679824